# Guava: iterates with intermediate processing

Tags: java, guava

**I've got:** array of objects: `{o1, o2, o3, o4, ...}`. Suppose I start my iteration from `o2` object. I can have a situation when there are few consequential same objects. I mean `o2` same `o3` same `o4`.

By `same` I understand `o1.getSomeField().equals(o2.getSomeField())`

**I want:** Iterates through array and do some processing each time I'm switching to not-same objects.

**Example:** Suppose `o2` same `o3` but not same `o4`. Then the steps of iteration:

- Switching from `o2` to `o3`
- Aha, they are the same, do nothing
- Switching from `o3` to `o4`
- `o3` and `o4` aren't the same. Do some extra logic on {o2, o3, o4} subarray

**Question:** How to do that? Is there something in Guava that will help me?

**Question2:** Is there any existed libraries, that allows me to divide my initial array into subarrays with the `same` elements? (By `same` I understand `o1.getSomeField().equals(o2.getSomeField())`)

Comment: To my knowledge there isn't anything in Guava which specifically makes this task easier. Consider writing a non-Guava implementation first and then figuring out where you can use Guava to make the code "nicer" – since that's a large part of what it does.

Comment: You should implement your iterator which will return the {o2,o3,o4} arrays on next calls then you could use guava iterators to do your logic

Comment: @maczikasz thanks! Please an example. Do you mean with help of `Iterators.any` method?

Comment: "How do I do this using something in Guava?" is not a question you should be asking. "How do I do this?" is fine, and you can also add "Is there something in Guava that helps with this?", but there are many things that are easiest to do just using JDK APIs and language constructs. Going out of your way to use Guava for something without any good reason for it is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my idea what I said in the comments, you could implement an iterator like this (maybe some modifications because this way it consumes the first element that's different so

`{ o1, o1, o2, o2, o3 }` will be `{ o1, o1, o2 } {o2, o3}` but that could be fixed easily

```
public class CollectingIterator implements Iterator<Collection<MyClass>> {


    private boolean hasNext;
    private LinkedList<MyClass> next = new LinkedList<MyClass>();

    private final Iterator<MyClass> baseIterator;

    public CollectingIterator(Iterator<MyClass> baseIterator) {
        this.baseIterator = baseIterator;
        toNext();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return hasNext;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<MyClass> next() {
        Collection<MyClass> next = new LinkedList<MyClass>(this.next);
        toNext();
        return next;
    }

    private void toNext() {
        next.clear();
        boolean isSame = true;
        while (baseIterator.hasNext() && isSame) {
            if (next.isEmpty()) {
                next.add(baseIterator.next());
            } else {
                final MyClass nextElement = baseIterator.next();
                final MyClass last = next.getLast();
                next.add(nextElement);
                if (!last.getSomeField().equals(nextElement.getSomeField())) {
                    isSame = false;
                }
            }
        }

        this.hasNext = baseIterator.hasNext() || !next.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Then you could user guavas [Iterables](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) or [FluentIterable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html) to do further logic. Although if it's a one off processing then you might be better off by the suggestion in the other answer

Answer (score 2):

Keep the previous element in a variable:

```
Foo previous = null;
for (Foo foo : iterable) {
    if (!foo.getSomeField().equals(previous.getSomeField())) {
        doSomething(foo);
    } 
    previous = foo;
}
```

Comment: This is not a guava implementation, furthermore the doSomethin only takes one parameter which is the last element, you'd have to iterate backward to find the {o2,o3,o4} array mentioned in the question

Comment: Well, in that case, add the current element to a list instead of calling doSomething(), and then do something else with the created list once the loop has ended. Guava is based on Java. And this is dead simple, pure Java. Every problem doesn't need a Guava class to be solved. If you really want to make it a Guava solution, use Lists.newArrayList() to create an empty list.

Comment: @JBNizet what about `ForwadingIterator` or `PeekingIterator`?

Comment: I don't see how they would help. And if they did, I don't see how it would make things simpler than my answer.

Comment: This will throw NPE, by the way. `previous` is `null` at the beginning of the first iteration, so `previous.getSomeField()` will fail.

Comment: I didn't read the question thoroughly enough I thought (from the title) that the question was aimed if this can be done in guava, and your answer didn't contain any indication whether it was possible or not